# Wait until pallet rack storage has enough space

Tags: anylogic

I would like to insert a wait or another similar block where my pallets have to wait until the pallet rack has enough space to store them. How could I do this? In my project my pallet rack has space for 80 pallets. When 50 pallets get stored at 8 am and 50 pallets at 11 am but the trucks arrive at 12 am to pick them it logically shows the error that there are not enough empty cells. The remaining 20 pallets should wait until it is enough space again after the truck takes 50 pallets.
[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMNJ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use different things:

- after your source a queue followed by a restricted area start with a maximum number of accepted agents equal to the capacity of your palletracks... with a restricted area end after your rack pick (recommended)
- after your source a queue followed by a hold block. You will block this hold when your palletrack capacity is at its maximum
- a wait block that will free agents only when your pallet racks have space

Comment: When I do it with a wait block what could the function be? I have a function spaceavailable (return storage.capacity() - storage.size() - reserved.size();) and the parameter storage type palletrack ans the collection reserved class pallets

Comment: you have other functions you can use for your pallet racks hasSpace() which tells you if a pallet rack has spaces that are neither reservered nor used.. so use that